# Reordering Pandas Table Headers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datatables, pivot-table

I am working with a Pivot Table in Pandas and I am facing an issue with the order of multi-level column headers.

Currently, I have the following column headers.
[image]

And, I want to reorder them to look like this
[image]

Is there any way to do this?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.swaplevel(1, 0, axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)
```